# Tree of NSProgresses

Tags: macos, cocoa

I try to understand logic of creating tree NSProgresses. But not everything smoothly for me. I try to implement global NSProgress manager which will observe all tasks and operations in application and asks permission for quieting if one of task don't completed. In my imagination it should be root NSProgress in which sub progresses will attach. And when we will quite from application we need ask fractionCompleted. It means that root NSProgress will recursively traverse through all child NSProgresses and calculate total progress. But on practice it do not.
I've made code which I use as testing stand (http://pastebin.com/CbXiFwCi). Please help me understand NSProgress logic because network is pure on documentation. Thank you.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.progress = [[NSProgress alloc] initWithParent:nil
                                              userInfo:nil];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        [self.progress becomeCurrentWithPendingUnitCount:0]; ///what I should set as pendingUnitCount?

        NSProgress * progressA = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:INT64_MAX-1];

        progressA.cancellable = NO;/// set cancellable to NO

        for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < INT64_MAX; i++)
        {
            //do work
            progressA.completedUnitCount ++;
        }

        [self.progress resignCurrent];
    });

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.progress becomeCurrentWithPendingUnitCount:0];///what I should set as pendingUnitCount?

        NSProgress * progressB = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:150];

        for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < 150; i++)
        {
            //do work
            progressB.completedUnitCount ++;
        }

        [self.progress resignCurrent];
    });
}

- (void)action:(id)sender
{
    double fractionCompleted = self.progress.fractionCompleted;///why fractionCompleted -> NAN?

    BOOL cancellable = self.progress.cancellable; ///why cancellable is YES if progressA.cancellable -> NO
}
```